# The need for thermal relief

Tags: pcb-design

When thru hole parts are to be soldered to a ground plane on a large PCB with thick copper the thermal relief process makes hand soldering easy. Cad systems are set up for this and work reasonably well .The relief process does increase trace impedence and reduce current carrying capacity. If a pcb were really thin relief is not as important as if the PCB is thick .If the copper area that the thru hole part is soldered to is not a big ground plane but a small island then can the relieving rules be relaxed? Is there a rule of thumb for connected copper area above which you should relieve?Does this rule change with pcb thickness like say 1oz,2oz.3oz? How extreme do things get with extreme copper?  And what about leaded Vs unleaded Solder.

Comment: I've soldered to 6 layer boards with 2oz thick copper with no relief using leaded solder. I had a really good station though and I needed to pull out the preheater to do it. It's not actually difficult for large pads where you can use a large tip. The pads that were actually a problem were the little chip components where one pad was connected to a plane. No rules of thumb as much as you just need to know what your equipment can do.

Comment: SDG Electronics reviews soldering irons by soldering to copper coins, which are far larger thermal masses than any fiberglass PCB plane. Thermal reliefs make soldering with low power irons quicker and may let you avoid switching from a fine rework tip to a high thermal load tip. But they're not usually required unless you have very limited equipment or must avoid heating the entire area around the part (e.g. thermally sensitive components).

Comment: @DKNguyen Reading that makes me want to get a preheater!

Comment: @Hearth They're great but extremely overpriced unless you get a potentially untrustworthy no-name Chinese one. I was using the "cheap" little Hakko  FR830-02 and that left quite a bit to be desired but the nice big ones cost more than even the most extravagant soldering stations plus accessories for no good reason.